# How can you create an EC2 Instance from a launch template with the node.js AWS SDK

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-sdk-nodejs

I have looked at the AWS node.js SDK and looked around google/youtube and can't seem to figure out how to use launch templates with the node.js SDK. I have seen how to launch a new EC2 instance and configure it but there must be a way to launch a template right?

I think I found a few working examples in python but the rest of my lambda function is in node.js so I would like to stick with it if I can.

Maybe there is a resource I missed somewhere, if someone could at least point me to that that would be great, thanks ahead of time.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use the [RunInstances](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/EC2.html#runInstances-property) method of the EC2 object of the SDK. Instead of providing all the specifics to launch the instance, you can simply provide the launch template as a parameter.

Untested example:

```js
const AWS = require('aws-sdk');

const params = {
  MaxCount: 1,
  LaunchTemplate: {
    LaunchTemplateId: 'STRING_VALUE',
    LaunchTemplateName: 'STRING_VALUE',
    Version: 'STRING_VALUE',
  },
};

new AWS.EC2({apiVersion: '2016-11-15'}).runInstances(params);
```

Comment: Thank you very much this looks like exactly what I was looking for, I'll try it out!

Comment: I slightly changed it (had to add a "MinCount" variable and take out the  "LaunchTemplateName" variable) but yeah that's pretty much it!